# How to prevent my application from causing Windows 8 to switch away from Start screen?

Tags: winapi, windows-8

My application is causing the following strange behavior on Windows 8:

Conditions:

1. My native WinAPI application is started automatically upon Windows 8 startup.
2. Windows remains at the Start screen immediately upon startup.

When my application creates a window, Windows switches to desktop away from the Start screen. The window created is toolbar window, it does not steal the user focus, used as status display.

This only happens when the window is being created not immediately after the startup, but some seconds later.

**My question:** How can I prevent Windows switching to desktop when my window appears?

Comment: Are you creating a visible window?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, a window is toolbar-style visible window

Comment: Well, that sounds like your problem. Perhaps you need to keep it hidden until the first time the desktop is shown. Even better would be not to start your app until the desktop shows. That way the user doesn't pay the startup cost until they really have to. Hate those apps that insist on starting when the system starts.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Application does network traffic accounting, and most users do prefer to have it start with Windows (it's configurable though). But I agree: right now it seems not showing the window till the user manually switches to the desktop is the only sane solution... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can manage start up applications. Turn it off for your application. And it should work.

Comment: Well, users do want the application to start on Windows startup. They just don't want its activity to "steal" the display to the desktop, away from the Start screen tiles (application does useful work in background).